# Enable a login button only if all text fields have verified success

Tags: ios, swift

I want to enable login button once all the condition satisfied for text field. I have added **editchange** event to two text fields through starboard.By default i have adding one label to text field with red background color to indicate(wrong) once user enters correct values in textfield then i need to change label color to green color. It is not working as except.

[image: First]

[image: Second]

My entire code:

```
import UIKit
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

class SignInFormViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!

    // Existing User
    @IBOutlet weak var existingEmailAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var existingPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            //Setting text fileds effect
        self.makeTextFiledEffect(textField: existingEmailAddressTextField, backColor: UIColor.red, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray)
        self.makeTextFiledEffect(textField: existingPasswordTextField, backColor: UIColor.red, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray)

        //Disable sing button by default
        signInButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    func makeTextFiledEffect(textField : UITextField, backColor : UIColor, borderColor : UIColor) {
        for viewPrevious in textField.subviews{
            if viewPrevious.tag == 1000{
                viewPrevious.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        let arrowView = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 5, height: textField.frame.size.height))
        arrowView.tag = 1000
        arrowView.backgroundColor = backColor
        textField.changeDynamicBorderColor(borderColor: borderColor)
        textField.addSubview(arrowView)
    }

    @IBAction func validateTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if sender.text?.count == 1 {
            if sender.text?.first == " " {
                sender.text = ""
                return
            }
        }
        guard
            let emaiTextField = existingEmailAddressTextField.text, !emaiTextField.isEmpty && self.validateEmail(emaiTextField)==true ,
            let password = existingPasswordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty
            else {
                self.makeTextFiledEffect(textField: sender, backColor: UIColor.red, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray)
                self.signInButton.isEnabled = false
                return
        }
        self.makeTextFiledEffect(textField: sender, backColor: UIColor.green, borderColor: UIColor.lightGray)
        signInButton.isEnabled = true

    }
    @IBAction func signInButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped")

    }



func validateEmail(_ candidate: String) -> Bool {

        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: candidate)
    }
}

extension UITextField
{
    func changeDynamicBorderColor(borderColor : UIColor){
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
    open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
//        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

You can find a similar question : [Enable a button in Swift only if all text fields have been filled out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941069/enable-a-button-in-swift-only-if-all-text-fields-have-been-filled-out)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: u r checking condition on api basis or u can also check empty textfield in if, else if condition

Comment: @DilipTiwari not get you

Comment: u r checking condition why sending value of textfield to paratmers of api ?

Comment: to changing current text field label color

Comment: can u share screen

Comment: added screen, and even i have added correct mail, it is not changing to green

Comment: u want to change textfield to green when entered correct email right?

Comment: Yes and  I have to enable button if password field also not contain empty

Comment: what about nick answer bro

Comment: check all the conditions in textField's `editingChanged` event.

Comment: @TheTiger check my validateTextField method

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below basic steps to achieve your goal:-

- Create a function which will perform all the validations(UI Level or API level or any validation). If any validation fails, it will return false, otherwise return true
- loginButton.isEnabled = returned value of above function

Comment: Yes, I hope, I am doing the same way, as per your suggestion I need to have one bool variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        self.validateField()
        return true
}

// MARK: - Validations

func validateField() -> Bool
{
    if (self.isValidEmail(testStr: txtEmail.text!) && strPassword.characters.count > 0 )
    {

        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = .true
        btn.backgroundColor = .green

        return true
    }
    else
    {
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = .false
        btn.backgroundColor = .red

        return false
    }
}

func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {


    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)

    if (emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr) == false)
    {

        print("Invalid Email")

        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }

}
```